# TRttiMethod::Invoke use

Tags: rtti, c++builder-2010

I would like to know how to use the Invoke method of the TRttiMethod class in C++Builder 2010.

This is my code

```
Tpp *instance=new Tpp(this);
TValue *args;

TRttiContext * ctx=new TRttiContext();
TRttiType * t = ctx->GetType(FindClass(instance->ClassName()));

TRttiMethod *m=t->GetMethod("Show");
m->Invoke(instance,args,0);
```

Show has no arguments and it is __published. When I execute I get a EInvocationError with message 'Parameter count mismatch'.

Can someone demonstrate the use of Invoke? Both no arguments and with arguments in the called method.

Thanks

Josep

Answer (score 4):

You get the error because you are telling Invoke() that you are passing in 1 method parameter (even though you really are not, but that is a separate bug in your code).  Invoke() takes an `OPENARRAY` of TValue values as input.  Despite its name, the `Args_Size` parameter is not the NUMBER of parameters being passed in, but rather is the INDEX of the last parameter in the array.  So, to pass 0 method parameters to Show() via Invoke(), set the `Args` parameter to NULL and the `Args_Size` parameter to -1 instead of 0, ie:

```
Tpp *instance = new Tpp(this);

TRttiContext *ctx = new TRttiContext;
TRttiType *t = ctx->GetType(instance->ClassType());

TRttiMethod *m = t->GetMethod("Show");
m->Invoke(instance, NULL, -1);

delete ctx;
```

Now, once you fix that, you will notice Invoke() start to raise an EInsufficientRtti exception instead.  That happens when Runtime Packages are enabled.  Unfortunately, disabling Runtime Packages will cause TRttiContext::GetType() to raise an EAccessViolation in TRttiPool::GetPackageFor() because of a known linker bug under C++:

[QC #76875, RAID #272782: InitContext.PackageTypeInfo shouldn't be 0 in a C++ module](http://qc.codegear.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=76875):

Which causes these bugs:

[QC #76672, RAID #272419: Rtti.pas is unusable in a C++ application](http://qc.codegear.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=76672)

[QC #76877, RAID #272767: AV in TRttiContext::GetType() when Runtime Packages are disabled](http://qc.codegear.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=76877)

So you are in a catch-22 situation.  The new RTTI system is not ready for production work in C++ yet.  You will have to use Delphi instead for the time being.

Comment: Are thoese bugs still in XE 7? Thanks.

Comment: I do not know. Two of the tickets mentioned (76875 and 76877) are still open. The closed ticket (76672) is because an AV is no longer raised when `PackageTypeInfo` is NULL.  I have no clue whether that root problem was ever fixed or not.  You will just have to try it and see what happens.